# How to group elements in HTML forms? Get a border around them?

Tags: html

I am relatively new to HTML.

I want to get a border around form elements which are similar.

For example, for Sign Up form :

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tag you are looking for is `<fieldset>`

```
<fieldset style="width:270px">
<legend>Contact details</legend> 
<label>Name:<br /></label>
<input type="text" name="name"><br />
<label>Email:<br />
<input type="text" name="email"></label><br /> 
<label>Mobile:<br />
<input type="text" name="mobile"></label><br /> 
</fieldset>
```

The result would be something like this :

[image]

And whatever is there in your `legend` tag is going to be displayed in the box as heading for the group.

The width determines the size of the box. If no width is mentioned, or you haven't used any CSS, the size of the rectangle would be that of the browser window.

Answer (score 4):

do you mean something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text"><br>
  Email: <input type="text"><br>
  Date of birth: <input type="text">
 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/991avcmv/

Answer (score 1):

Using the `<legend>Sign Up</legend>` tags

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do this is:-

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Contact details</legend>
<label>Email:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" /></label><br />
<label>Mobile:<br />
<input type="text" name="mobile" /></label><br />
<label>Telephone:<br />
<input type="text" name="telephone" /></label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Sign up:</legend>
   <label>Name:</label>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
   <label>Email: </label>
   <br>
   <input type="email" name="email"/><br>
    <label>Date of birth:</label>
   <br>
  <input type="text" name="dob"/>
 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```